# Retrieve all users based on where condition of relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to build a search system for my users.

The first part of this was easy as all the information I was searching was in the same table.

The second part involves searching for users based upon a provided IP address. For this I am using:

```
$users = User::with(array('login' => function($q){
                $q->where('ip_address', Input::get('ipaddress'));
            }))->paginate(10);
```

However this is returning all users, rather than just those that meet the IP address requirements. Where am I going wrong? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: What you want is an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$users = User::whereHas('login', function ($q) {
    $q -> where('ip_address', Input::get('ipaddress'));
}) -> paginate(10);
```

Try it!

Comment: I had just found `whereHas` and figured it out. But this is exactly how I did it!

Comment: It is not. When you use `with()` -  your `where` condition  returnd all users including `login`, and if login relation doesn't fit the condition - it will be included like `null` entity. But when you use `whereHas` - it filters users by relation condition